# jQuery - trying to show a div as a pop-up displays the div within the page layout

Tags: jquery

I am trying to do something like this in my jQuery:

```
$("#loading").show();
```

and here is the `#loading` div which I have as `display:none` at the bottom of the screen:

```
<div id="loading" style="display:none; ">
  <p><img src="img/ajax-loader.gif" /> Please Wait</p>
</div>
```

I realize that the `.show()` function just makes things appear, but how could I display this overlayed over the content of the screen since that div just has a `.gif` spinner icon that signals to the user to wait?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the way I do it is by creating a dialog box.

```
  $("#loading").dialog({
                    height: 140,  
                    width:160,
                    modal: true,
                    resizable : false, 
                    draggable : false,
                    closeOnEscape: false   //So that dont close on escape
                   });
$(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();   //No title bar
         $(".ui-dialog").css("padding","0px");  //Remove extra spacing
```

and removing it on ajax call end.

**Other ways::**

1. [Use JQUERY BLOCK UI PLUGIN](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/)
2. [Using CSS  FIXED Position](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3674753/1085285)

Comment: yeah I know it gets the dialog to render as a popup, but it has a background and a heading that I don't want to appear there. I need to just have the .gif file appear like a spinner image that signals to wait.

Comment: yes it got rid of the title bar, but somehow not the background.  It there a way to make the background not show up?  Thanks! :)

Comment: @Genadinik change              .ui-dialog,.ui-dialog,.ui-widget, .ui-widget-content, .ui-corner-all, .foo, .ui-draggable, .ui-resizable {background: yellow !important or something}​

Comment: I see - you mean to re-style them using css?

Comment: thank you - one last question...since I want the background to appear on all other dialogs, how can I make the background not show up using the jQuery JS?

Comment: you can change that dialog related css in your jquery.ui.css. so that it will be changed for each and every dialog box